# wordpress template file quick tag more no working

Tags: wordpress

i created a page template to be used as my front/home page with the wordpress loop in it, here is the code:

```
<?php query_posts('posts_per_page=10'); ?>
<?php
/* Run the loop to output the posts.
 * If you want to overload this in a child theme then include a file
 * called loop-index.php and that will be used instead.
 */
 get_template_part( 'loop', 'idex' );
?>
```

but the problem is that the qiuicktag `<!--more-->` is not working , they always show the whole content. isn't the `<!--more-->` stored in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the  tag is just stored inside the text of the field post_content in the wp_posts table.

If you do not want WordPress to show the whole content, then use "the_excerpt" or call "the_content" in your loop with the correct parameters:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More

Just use a conditional tag in your loop.php where you call "the_content":

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page()) {
   the_excerpt(); // or the_content( $more_link_text , $strip_teaser, $more_file );
} else {
  the_content();
}
```

I hope this solves the problem. Otherwise there could be a bug or problem with your template regarding the "the_content"-function.

Comment: yea i think of using "the_excerpt", but it has some problem counting the Chinese words, so i decide to stick with manual editing with the `<!--more-->`. anyway now i found the problem you just need to add the `<?php $more = 0; ?>` before the loop, everything will be fine. by the way, do you know any good wordpress book that really dig deep into it, cause correcting all these little cracks by googling is not  that much fun, i want a book that tell the structure of wordpress, not just about theme and plugins , more about the files outside of the wp-content dir.

Comment: Hey, I am not sure if there is a book which is analysing WordPress in the level of detail which you possibly would prefer ... the best and most detailed book (out of 5) which I was reading about WordPress is called ["Professional WordPress - Design and Development" by Hal Stern, David Damstra and Brad Williams](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-WordPress-Wrox-Programmer/dp/0470560541/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1315138463&sr=8-1). Also a new book called "Professional WordPress - Plugin Development" is said to be very good and might go deeper into the actual structure of WordPress.